# Eclipse script to refactor

Tags: java, eclipse, scripting, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have hundreds of projects in my workspace, some of which are dependent on others. I have a generated Java file (Example.java) with static fields that are being referenced throughout the codebase. I have also generated files within specific modules that have these static fields. I want to migrate the references to the fields to the modularized version of the fields that belong in the specific packages.

For instance, Example.java contains:

```
public static final ObjectType OT1 = ObjectTypeFactory.makeObject("OT1");
public static final ObjectType OT2 = ObjectTypeFactory.makeObject("OT2");
public static final ObjectType OT3 = ObjectTypeFactory.makeObject("OT3");

Then Modularized Java files within the packages look something like:
Mod1.java
public static final ObjectType OT1 = ObjectTypeFactory.makeObject("OT1");

Mod2.java
public static final ObjectType OT2 = ObjectTypeFactory.makeObject("OT2");

Mod3.java
public static final ObjectType OT3 = ObjectTypeFactory.makeObject("OT3");
```

I want to move the references to Example.OT1 to Mod1.OT1 throughout my codebase, as well as change the rest of them. I have thousands of such changes to make.

Comment: You may also use Maven to handle inter-project dependencies in order not to rely too much on Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

JDT supports [refactoring scripts](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-refactoring.htm). However I have never used them so I do not know what is possible.

Otherwise you may try using [Eclipse EASE](https://eclipse.org/ease) coupled with the JDT APIs for refactoring and in particular the [move static field refactoring](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Frefactoring%2Fpackage-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks, I had already been through these before. Are there any tutorials for this or a step by step as to how to use the refactoring api? Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Sure, I have grouped a few links here: https://github.com/JnRouvignac/AutoRefactor/wiki/Useful-links